Is quotient map always an open map?
Could someone please have a look at this solution? This is what I know about quotient maps: Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces; let $p : X \to Y$ be a surjective map.
The map $p$ is said to be a quotient map provided a subset $U$ of $Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. And it can be a closed or an open map.
But why does the solution assume a quotient map to be an open map. Are quotient maps always open?


No, quotient maps don't need to be open. You need to show $p^{-1}(p(U)) = U$ i.e. that $U$ is a saturated open set. And this follows from the assumption that $p^{-1}({y})$ is connected for all $y\in Y$. Then it will follow that $p(U)$ is open.

@Jakobian Thanks for the response. But why does he directly say that  " Consider the subsets $p(U)$ and $p(V)$ of $Y$: they are both open (since $U$ and $V$ are
open, and $p$ is a quotient map). " Did he skip a step?

Most likely. I can't speak for someone else, but I wouldn't assume lack of knowledge to claim that quotient maps are open from someone that's trying to teach general topology.

They skipped the step verifying that both $U, V$ are saturated (true but needs a proof).

Quotient maps are in general not open maps.
As an example consider $p : [0,1] \to [0,1]/\{0,1\}$ which collapses the set $\{0,1\}$ to a single point. The set $[0,1/2)$ is open in $[0,1]$, but $p([0,1/2))$ is not open in $ [0,1]/\{0,1\}$ because $p^{-1}(p([0,1/2))) = [0,1/2) \cup \{1\}$ is not open in $[0,1]$.
Note, however, that open surjective maps $f : X \to Y$ are quotient maps. In fact, if $U \subset Y$ has the property that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, then $U = f(f^{-1}(U))$ is open in $Y$.
The argument "$p(U)$ and $p(V)$ are open since $U$ and $V$ are open and $p$ is a quotient map" is indeed inadequate (or at least too much shortened) because quotient maps are in general not open.
However, under the additional assumption that the fibers $p^{-1}(y)$ are connected we can prove that $p(U)$ and $p(V)$ are open. More precisely, we can show that
$$p^{-1}(p(U)) = U \text{ and } p^{-1}(p(V)) = V .$$
Note that this does not mean that $p$ is an open map since we do not consider the images of arbitrary open subsets of $X$.
We now prove $p^{-1}(p(U)) = U$; $p^{-1}(p(V)) = V$ is similar.
$U \subset p^{-1}(p(U))$ is of course true for any function $p$. It remains to prove $p^{-1}(p(U)) \subset U$, i.e. $p^{-1}(y) \subset U$ for all $y \in p(U)$. The sets $p^{-1}(y) \cap U$ and $p^{-1}(y) \cap V$ are disjoint open subsets of $p^{-1}(y)$ whose union is $p^{-1}(y)$. Since $p^{-1}(y)$ is connected, we conclude that either $p^{-1}(y) \cap U = \emptyset$ or $p^{-1}(y) \cap V = \emptyset$. Write $y = p(x)$ with $x  \in U$. Then $x \in p^{-1}(y) \cap U$, i.e. $p^{-1}(y) \cap U \ne \emptyset$. Hence $p^{-1}(y) \cap V = \emptyset$, thus $p^{-1}(y) \subset X \setminus V = U$.
